# Creating a table based on font size for a slide deck with Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am working on a slide deck and I am trying to get all the text boxes that have a font size of 20, into a table with the number of the slide where it appears as second column. I developed this code, but it marks an error, this is what I have so far:

```
function createTableWithText() {
  // Open the current presentation
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = presentation.getSlides();

  // Create a new slide
  var newSlide = presentation.appendSlide();
  var page = slides.length + 1;

  // Create a table with 2 columns
  var numRows = 1; // You can adjust the number of rows as needed
  var numCols = 2;
  var table = newSlide.insertTable(numRows, numCols);

  // Get all text boxes with font size 20
  var textboxes = presentation.getSlides().map(function(slide) {
    return slide.getShapes().filter(function(shape) {
      return shape.getText().getTextStyle().getFontSize() === 20;
    });
  }).flat();

  // Add the full name of the text box and page number to the table
  for (var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
    var textbox = textboxes[i];
    var text = textbox.getText().asString();

    table.getCell(i, 0).getText().setText(text);
    table.getCell(i, 1).getText().setText(String(page));
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a table index for my slide deck, the only thing that they have in common is the font size. When I run my current code, an error appears saying this: Exception: Page element is not of type shape.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.